# An odd json usage

Tags: javascript, json

I saw a part of javascript code on [MDN](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-in-firefox-4/) and I am wondering how to work below code and what does it mean ?

```
var obj = { get x() { return 17; } };
```

Comment: read all about the get operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the keyword `get` just classifies `x()` as a getter, and appears to self-invoke. It's not supported in jScript (IE) and it's not a reserved word.

You'd reference it like so: `obj.x; // 17`

In lamen's terms, these will behave identically:

```
var foo = { get x() { return 17; } };  
document.write(foo.x);​ // 17

var bar = { x: function() { return 17; } };  
document.write(bar.x());​ // 17
```

Comment: That's not identically, `foo.x` and `bar.x()`

Comment: I said they'll behave identically, not that they're coded identically.

Answer (score 1):

`var obj = { get x() { return 17; } };` equals to:

```
var obj = {
    x: 17
}
```

Or also:

```
var obj = {
    x: (function(){
        return 17;
    })()
}
```

Which means that `var obj` declares an object and `get x() { return 17; }` declares a property of obj object and has the value of 17:

```
var myVar = obj.x;//Equals to 17
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited and fixed the post. I guess now it's correct

Comment: What "get" mean ? . I thing the two thing not same. You can see that `dir(obj)` from javascript console.

Comment: "get x() { return 17; }" == "x = 17". So this is the proposal of "get": calculate the return value of the function (in case, 17) and set the "x" var as this value.

Answer (score 0):

That is specifying a getter for the x property, it has nothing to do with JSON. You're confused because JSON is a valid initializer for a JS object, however, not all JS initializers are valid JSON.

That syntax means that when you read from `obj.x`, it will call that function to get its value.